# How to send json into snowplow using iglu webook in python

Tags: python, snowplow

I have a json full of event data that I need to send into snowplow in python using an iglu webhook but having trouble finding any solid guidance on this. Most of the documentation I've been able to find relates to tracking specific events and sending the data through but I need to backfill historical data in the same manner I'll fill forward looking data hence having to send a large json with activity history at the outset.

Is this possible using snowplow/python/iglu or am I approaching the problem incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

This question is getting old and OP may have moved on, but I'll leave an answer for anyone else who might stumble upon it.

A Snowplow collector (eg, the [stream-collector](https://github.com/snowplow/stream-collector)) receives data over HTTP. Any method of sending an HTTP request should work in theory, however there are specific SDKs that address common use cases. For Python specifically, there is the [snowplow-python-tracker](https://github.com/snowplow/snowplow-python-tracker). You can refer to the full documentation here: [Snowplow Python Tracker Docs](https://docs.snowplowanalytics.com/docs/collecting-data/collecting-from-own-applications/python-tracker/).

You do not need to be using an Iglu webhook. You can point your Python tracker instance directly to your collector via the existing request paths, which are documented [here](https://docs.snowplowanalytics.com/docs/getting-started-on-snowplow-open-source/setup-snowplow-on-aws/setup-the-snowplow-collector/configure-the-scala-stream-collector-2/#configuring-custom-paths). Yes, one of these paths is for requests via the Iglu webhook adapter but that is meant to be used in specific situations where you don't control the environment, in which the tracker is instantiated, eg third-pary vendor systems.